# RedirectToAction not return View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect to action and get a new view (a new page) with no success. While debugging,  I'm reaching the controller but not getting the view (the page URL is not changed).

With Fiddler I see that the page returns the right view result but in the browser the URL is not changed!

When shopping cart is empty, I would like to redirect to a new page a display the error message.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public RedirectToRouteResult PlaceOrder(DeliveryDetails deliveryDetails)
    {           
        if (UserCart.IsEmpty)
        {

            TempData["errorMsg"] = "Error: Cart is empty";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
        }
        else
        {
             InsertOrder();
        }


     }
```

**ErrorController:**

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**ErrorController View:**

```
  @TempData["errorMsg"]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ActionResult` instead of  `RedirectToRouteResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PlaceOrder(DeliveryDetails deliveryDetails)
{           
   // .....
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
}
```

Comment: With Fiddler I see that the page returns the right view result but in the browser the URL is not changed!

Answer (score 0):

Then I would surmise that UserCart.IsEmpty is evaluating to false. What does your Error Index route look like? Also, you're better off returning a base ActionResult from a controller action in case you need to return a view. Presumably there's more code in the PlaceOrder method because that won't compile as it stands

Comment: I don't have route for this. do I must add it?